# Converting between coordinate systems with integrals/infinitesimals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I recently discovered for myself an interesting trick that I didn't know you were allowed to do.

Let's say I have the expression:

$ydx$

And I want to convert it to cylindrical coordinates. When I was solving this specific problem assigned to me, I did this:

$(rsin(\theta)) d(rcos\theta)$

$(rsin(\theta)) (-rsin(\theta)) d\theta$

$ydx = -r^2sin^2(\theta)d\theta $

When I went about solving the problem, I got the correct answer.

**Can someone explain why this is allowed and how it works?** Or if it isn't allowed, why it worked in this specific scenario? I have never seen this done before nor have I ever been taught that this is an acceptable thing to do when converting between coordinate systems.

Here is the problem that I had to work on for those who are curious:

> A magnetic field intensity vector, $H$ , is described by the vector function. $H (x,y,z)=9y\hat{x}$ [A/m]. Calculate the circulation of $H$  around a circle of radius $r=7$ [meters] in the $x-y$ plane, traversed in the $+\hat{\phi}$-direction. Give the answer in units of [A]. Give three significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

No you are not

$d(rcos\theta)=((-rsin(\theta))+r^`cos\theta))d\theta$

it worked in that case because r is constant